# How to decrypt cipher text without knowing the algorithm used to encrypt it?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

The following is the encrypted text:

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

any ideas how to decrypt this?

Comment: Voting to close. This is completely off-topic for security.se. Even for crypto.se this is off-topic.

Comment: We are not a decrypting service. As you can imagine, if we allowed questions like this, we would be flooded with random strings.